# PHP MySQL edit form select dropdown preselected

Tags: php, mysql

I have certainly browsed and just haven't been able to get this seemingly easy answer!

I have a form where I can update records, and I can also edit them by clicking on the edit button I made. When I click to edit them, I obviously want the current settings to be chosen by default. Through $_GET variables, I have prefilled in the text inputs with their correct values from the DB.

However, I have three dropdown lists, and I am unable to get these to choose their correct value and name.

My form, for one example, has a dropdown list of all my users coming from a query of:

```
SELECT
    users.id AS 'Users ID',
    users.first_name AS 'User First Name',
    users.last_name AS 'User Last Name'
FROM users
ORDER BY users.first_name;
```

With the following it is correctly showing the list of users by name, and the values are being sent as IDs to the DB

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose User</label><br />
    <select name="userid">
    <?php
        while($usersrow = $usersresult->fetch_assoc()) {
        //Display Customer Info
        $output = '<option value="'.$usersrow['User ID'].'">'.$usersrow['User First Name'].' '.$usersrow['User Last Name'].'</option>';

        //Echo output
        echo $output;                   
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

With this as a setup, does anybody know how I can go to my edit field and have my dropdown preselected where the values remain the users ID? I have tried quite a few different ways including concatening with ternary if, and other $_GET variables of $id (for user id) and $name (for user name), but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated!

### **EDIT**

To put it a bit more simply...I am trying to have my dropdown be preselected based off of a $id $_GET variable that matches the value in a dropdown option.

Thanks

Comment: add a `selected` attribute as appropriate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the selected attribute for the option that matches the userId being edited:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Choose User</label><br />
    <select name="userid">
    <?php
        while($usersrow = $usersresult->fetch_assoc()) {
        //Display Customer Info
        if($usersrow['User ID'] == $_GET['userid']){
          $selected = "selected";
        }else{
          $selected = "";
        }
        $output = '<option value="'.$usersrow['User ID'].'" '.$selected.'>'.$usersrow['User First Name'].' '.$usersrow['User Last Name'].'</option>';

        //Echo output
        echo $output;                   
        }
    ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I found this one to be the best fit for my needs...only one small change was required (but that was just a change of $_GET variable that you couldn't have seen from my code!), so this worked very nicely. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can try this..

```
<select name= "USER LIST">
  <option value="">Choose user </option>
  <option value="User1"<?php if($record['User ID']== 'User1'){ echo 'selected'; }?>>USER 1</option>
                       <option value="User2"<?php if($record['User ID']== 'User1'){ echo 'selected'; }?>>USER 2</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
    <option value="<?php echo $row['softcode']; ?>"
     <?php if ($rows['office_type'] == $row['softcode']): ?>  
        selected="selected" 
     <?php endif ?>>
    <?php echo $row['description']; ?>
    </option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
       if ($usersrow['id']==$_GET['id']) {
             $selected = "selected";
       } else {
             $selected = "";
       }
       $output = '<option '.$selected.' value="'.$usersrow['User ID'].'" >'.$usersrow['User  First Name'].' '.$usersrow['User Last Name'];

    $output.='</option>';
```

Comment: Or... $usersrow['id'] == $_GET['id'] ? $selected = " selected " : $selected=" ";

Comment: Thanks for the comment...@Evis was just easier to implement into my code as he had the full code, so I went with his answer. But your logic was good, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this:

```
<?php
    while($usersrow = $usersresult->fetch_assoc()) {
    //Display Customer Info
    $output = '<option value="'.$usersrow['User ID'].'"'. $usersrow['User ID']== $_GET['id'] ? "selected" : "" . '" >'.$usersrow['User First Name'].' '.$usersrow['User Last Name'].'</option>';

    //Echo output
    echo $output;                   
    }
?>
```

The magic part to see if `$_GET['id']` matches `$userrow['id']`, if it does then echo selected else nothing:

```
$usersrow['User ID']== $_GET['id'] ? "selected" : ""
```

Comment: I tried this one first....but my select options were all empty. I am not sure why this happened, as I made sure the variables were correct, but the logic behind this was good and in fact was very similar to my efforts as well...but neither one quite worked as planned.